# Illegal string offset for array within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the main array called `$quizzes` which contains the collection of `$Quiz`.
Each `$Quiz` has the following fields: `$Quiz['correct']` gives me the number of correct questions.

I can get the number of correct questions for 12th quiz using `$quizzes[12]['correct']`

However, since these quizzes are not displayed in order, I decided to define a new array:

```
$listoftests = array('$quizzes[30]','$quizzes[51]');
```

In my head, `$listoftests[0]['correct']` should be equal to `$quizzes[30]['correct']` but it's giving me

> **Warning:** Illegal string offset 'correct' in
>   /demo.php
>   on line 14 $

when I try to `echo $listoftests[0]['correct'];`

Comment: what are you trying to there is n offset `correct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this `$listoftests = array('$quizzes[30]','$quizzes[51]');` These are considered as two strings `$quizzes[30]` and `$quizzes[51]`. You should remove single quotes `'` and try again.

**Change this:**

```
$listoftests = array('$quizzes[30]','$quizzes[51]');
```

**To:**

```
$listoftests = array($quizzes[30],$quizzes[51]);
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing this

```
$listoftests = array('$quizzes[30]','$quizzes[51]');
```

you created array of 2 strings. That's it. Not an array of arrays.

You should remove quotes. And you can also use isset() to check if array item exists.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quote and it shell work fine `$listoftests = array($quizzes[30],$quizzes[51]);`

Answer (score 1):

> @GRS you can do it in two way:

```
//case one where the element will be of string type
<?php
  $quizzes[30] = 3;
  $quizzes[51] = 32;
  $listoftests = array("$quizzes[30]","$quizzes[51]");
  var_dump($listoftests);

  //or

 //case two where the element will be of integer type
 <?php
  $quizzes[30] = 3;
  $quizzes[51] = 32;
  $listoftests = array($quizzes[30],$quizzes[51]);
  var_dump($listoftests);
```